# Are functions valid keys for javascript object properties?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to use functions as keys in a javascript object. The following works, at least in Chrome:

```
var registry = {};
function Foo(){  };
function Bar(){  };
registry[Foo] = 42;
registry[Bar] = 43;
alert(registry[Foo] + " < " + registry[Bar]);
```

Is this covered by the standard? By which browsers is it supported?

Comment: Well, worked in Chrome. So it might work in Safari and Firefox

Comment: i think it is like you alert a function, somehow the engine parses it as a string because it is permissive... But I'ld say it is not a good idea, unless you cast it as a string yourself before (is such thing possible I wonder)

Comment: The keys of any kind of any dictionary-class object must have a well defined == operation. Such an operation can not be defined for functions (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem).

Comment: @RobertHensing if so then how does `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` work? `addEventListener` will not add same callback twice for same event. And obviously `removeEventListener` needs to recognise the callback being removed. I did not understand the Rice's theorem, but in my mind a function can be represented as a pointer. Why isn't this used? Update: keys of type object do not work either.

Comment: [Specification](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-property-accessors-runtime-semantics-evaluation), [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#property_names). Related: [Why does \[\]\[\[\]\] evaluate to undefined?](/q/49310701/4642212).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Everything you put between square brackets is converted into a string, and this happens even if you put a function, a date, a regexp... So there, you're actually creating an object like this:

```
var registry = {
    "function Foo(){  }" : 42,
    "function Bar(){  }" : 43
};
```

This is a default behaviour, it works in IE too if you were wondering. It was actually exploited by John Resig in his [famous `addEvent` function](http://ejohn.org/projects/flexible-javascript-events/).

Comment: Note that functions with different closures can be converted to the same string, and access the same property.

From the node console:
    > var maker = function(a) { return function(){ console.log(a); }; };
    > var bb = maker('bb')
    > bb()
    bb
    > var cc = maker('dd')
    > cc()
    dd
    > var test = {};
    > test[bb]='AA'
    'AA'
    > test[bb]
    'AA'
    > bb()
    bb
    > test
    { 'function (){ console.log(a); }': 'AA' }
    > test[cc] = 'DD'
    'DD'
    > test
    { 'function (){ console.log(a); }': 'DD' }
    > test[bb]
    'DD'
    > test[cc]
    'DD'

Answer (score 8):

> **ECMAScript 5.1 - Section 11.2.1:**
>
> The production `MemberExpression  : MemberExpression [ Expression ]` is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let baseReference be the result of evaluating MemberExpression .
> 2. Let baseValue be GetValue(baseReference).
> 3. Let propertyNameReference  be the result of evaluating Expression.
> 4. Let propertyNameValue  be GetValue(propertyNameReference).
> 5. Call CheckObjectCoercible(baseValue).
> 6. **Let propertyNameString  be ToString(propertyNameValue).**
> 7. If the syntactic production that is being evaluated is contained in strict mode code, let  strict be true, else let 
>       strict be false.
> 8. Return a value of type Reference whose base value is base Value and whose referenced name is 
>      propertyNameString , and whose strict mode flag is strict.

So when using `obj[whatever]`, `whatever` is converted to a string. For a function this will be a string containing the sourcecode of the function.

Example:

```
js> var func = function() { return 'hi'; };
js> function helloworld() { return 'hello world'; }
js> var obj = {};
js> obj[func] = 123;
js> obj[helloworld] = 456;
js> obj
({'function () {\n    return "hi";\n}':123,
  'function helloworld() {\n    return "hello world";\n}':456
})
```